# Menu sanfona com opção aberta por padrão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando um [Menu Accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp), baseando em um [exemplo](https://codepen.io/mrs_snow/pen/vEvzaL) que achei na internet, no entanto, estou lutando pra tentar fazer com que fique uma opção em aberto por padrão, igualmente nesse [exemplo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) aqui.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```js
//faq toggle stuff 
$('.togglefaq').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var notthis = $('.active').not(this);
notthis.find('.icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-minus');
notthis.toggleClass('active').next('.faqanswer').slideToggle(300);
 $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");
$(this).children('i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
});
```

```css
/* FAQ COLLAPSE/EXPAND STYLES */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.faqanswer {
 display: none;
 width: 590px;
 background: #e5e5e5;
 padding: 12px 20px 0 30px; 
}

.faqanswer p {
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 17px; 
}


a.active {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.togglefaq {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 width: 590px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.icon-plus {
 color: #5ec4cd;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 float:left;
}

.icon-minus {
 color: #5ec4cd;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 float:left;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="togglefaq"><i class="icon-plus"></i> How do you tell an introverted computer scientist from an extroverted computer scientist?</a>
          <div class="faqanswer">
            <p>An extroverted computer scientist looks at <em>your</em> shoes when he talks to you.
</p>
   </div>
   
       <a href="#" class="togglefaq"><i class="icon-plus"></i> How many programmers does it take to change a light bulb?</a>
          <div class="faqanswer">
             <p>None, that's a hardware problem.
</p>
   </div>

        <a href="#" class="togglefaq"><i class="icon-plus"></i> What's the object-oriented way to become wealthy?</a>
          <div class="faqanswer">
             <p>Inheritance.
</p>
   </div>    
   
           <a href="#" class="togglefaq"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Why do programmers like UNIX?</a>
          <div class="faqanswer">
             <p>unzip, strip, touch, finger, grep, mount, fsck, more, yes, fsck, fsck, fsck, umount, sleep
</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: Tá e cade o seu código? Qual código é o que vc está usando? Vc citou 3 exemplos. Mas sem saber exatamente o que vc tem ai fica difícil te responder com precisão

Comment: Editei com o código que eu estou usando agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc nem precis mexer no JS para arrumar isso. Basta já deixar uma das opções do seu menu já selecionada com a classe `.active` setada. Tipo assim, eu já deixei o primeir `<a href="#" class="togglefaq active">` com a classe `.active` definida.

Em seguida na `<div class="faqanswer">` como o `display` é definido pelo `slideToggle` basta que vc também já o deixe como `display:block` definido, no caso na `style="display:block"`

Veja como ficou o resultado, repare que o primeiro item já aparece aberto, e se vc clicar nele ele vai se fechar.

```js
//faq toggle stuff 
$('.togglefaq').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var notthis = $('.active').not(this);
    notthis.find('.icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-minus');
    notthis.toggleClass('active').next('.faqanswer').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
});
```

```css
/* FAQ COLLAPSE/EXPAND STYLES */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.faqanswer {
    display: none;
    width: 590px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    padding: 12px 20px 0 30px;
}

.faqanswer p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
}


a.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.togglefaq {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    width: 590px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.icon-plus {
    color: #5ec4cd;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.icon-minus {
    color: #5ec4cd;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="togglefaq active"><i class="icon-plus"></i> How do you tell an introverted computer scientist from an
    extroverted computer scientist?</a>
<div class="faqanswer" style="display:block">
    <p>An extroverted computer scientist looks at <em>your</em> shoes when he talks to you.
    </p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="togglefaq"><i class="icon-plus"></i> How many programmers does it take to change a light bulb?</a>
<div class="faqanswer">
    <p>None, that's a hardware problem.
    </p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="togglefaq"><i class="icon-plus"></i> What's the object-oriented way to become wealthy?</a>
<div class="faqanswer">
    <p>Inheritance.
    </p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="togglefaq "><i class="icon-plus"></i> Why do programmers like UNIX?</a>
<div class="faqanswer" >
    <p>unzip, strip, touch, finger, grep, mount, fsck, more, yes, fsck, fsck, fsck, umount, sleep
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, eu lembro de ter feito isso, só que quando clicava nos outros elementos ele continuava aberto

Comment: @SérgioMachado talvez tenha faltado algum detalhe quando vc fez, Pq o slidetoggle muda o display do elemento direto no style da tag. Mas que bom que resolveu ai. Boa sorte no projeto qq coisa estamos ai